# Why does std::move take rvalue reference as argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), `move` has signature

```
template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) noexcept;
```

Why does it take a rvalue reference `T&& t` as its arugment?

Also when I tried the following code

```
void foo(int&& bar) {
    cout << "baz" << endl;
}

int main(){
    int a;
    foo(a);
}
```

I got an error from the compiler "an rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue"

What is going on? I'm so confused.

Comment: You assumed that `T&& t` is an rvalue reference. This is premature, There's no way to say whether `T&& t` is an rvlaue reference or not until you know what `T` is. When `T` is deduced, the language rules (type deduction and reference collapsing) are deliberately crafted to make `T&& t` switch between rvalue and lvalue reference depending on the external circumstances.

Comment: It's confusing. The double-amp && has either of two meanings depending on context. On a template-parameter it denotes a "forwarding reference" .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not an rvalue reference, but a [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references); which could preserve the value category of the argument. That means `std::move` could take both lvalue and rvalue, and convert them to rvalue unconditionally.

> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to forward it by means of std::forward. Forwarding references are either:
>
> 1) function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue
>   reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same
>   function template:
>
> 2) auto&& except when deduced from a brace-enclosed initializer list.

On the other hand, `int&&` is an rvalue reference; note the difference here, if a function template parameter has type `T&&` with template parameter `T`, i.e. a deduced type `T`, the parameter is a forwarding reference.